# git branches show diffs but merge does nothing

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-svn

I have two branches, "svnbranch" that's updated via "git svn rebase" and "master" used by other git users that push their changes.

Right now when I do "git diff master" I see some changes in master that I want to merge into svnbranch so I can "dcommit" them. However, when I do "git merge master" nothing happens:

git checkout svnbranch

git diff master

... some changes are shown

git merge master

Already up-to-date

Why don't the changes get merged in?

[Note: What I'm really trying to do is generate a git repo that's a mirror of our SVN repo and manually merge changes both ways. I tried automating that but can't get that running smoothly so I manually merge every few days]

Comment: `git svn dcommit` is a bad idea for that as it will rewrite all the commit objects and actually commit them one by one to the SVN server, effectively removing the previous author information. Afterwards it will fetch the change sets from the SVN server again and rewrite the Git objects to match them (and also include SVN’s revision id in the commit message).

Comment: Is there a better way to send changes back up to SVN than dcommit? I've been thinking that maybe I should use actual svn commits to push changes back up but was afraid I would just do a poor rewrite of dcommit.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only external interface the SVN server provides is the SVN interface itself, so Git is bound to its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Then have a look at [SubGit](http://subgit.com) project as SVN<->Git mirror (both Git and SVN are writable and are constantly kept in sync). The installation can be done in one command:

```
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repo
```

or in 2-3 steps for more precise control over translation options

```
$ subgit configure path/to/svn/repo
$ #edit path/to/svn/repo/conf/subgit.conf and path/to/svn/repo/conf/authors.txt
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repo
```

and you never need to merge SVN and Git manually.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting but from the front page it seems like I have to have full control of my SVN server, which I don't.